# What cryptocurrency is most suitable to send small amounts?

Tags: dust, micropayments

I'd like to build a service to allow users to send small amounts, e.g. equal to $0.5-$1 per transaction without having to pay enormous (in relation to the amount sent) fees.

I read that technically bitcoin allows to send 0.00001 BTC a a minimum amount and it's $0.44 currently. But the commission will be larger than the amount sent to it doesn't make sense.

So, are there other cryptocurrencies where I can send such small amounts and pay something that is more reasonable?

Comment: You may use [Lightning Network](https://lightning.network/), a Bitcoin Layer 2 solution for micropayments. It's instant, cheap, and reliable.

Answer (score 3):

Other chains might be off topic here, but Bitcoin offers you at least two options. You can choose one from three, the first two are Bitcoin:

1. Enhance your calm. Using minimum fees it'll take longer, but it might cost as few as ten cents.
2. Use the Lightning Network or some other second layer system or side chain.
3. Use an alternative cheaper chain.

Answer (score 2):

With lightning you can send 1 sat (or even less) and there is almost no fee.

Comment: Indeed, I don't see why anyone would look for "another cryptocurrency" when the Lightning Network just works. Can send down to millisat (1/1000 of a sat) with very low fees. Depending on who you are sending to, if for example you make frequent payments to one node, you can just open a channel to that node.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, for all coins, if you use the native wallet (full node wallet) the fees will be as you want.

Just take a coin that you like, install the desktop full node wallet and see how small the fee is.